# DataTemplate Image biding wih byte array

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

Will picture store as Image in database and retrieve as byte array load to DataTemplate  Image automatically?

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Image">
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Image Height="10" Width="10" Source="{Binding Picture}" Stretch="Uniform"></Image>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [`IValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) in the binding.